# If the difference of cubes of two consecutive integers is a square, then the square can be written as the sum of squares of two different integers.

Tags: number-theory

How can i prove the statement that if the difference of cubes of two consecutive integers is an integral power of 2, then the integer with power 2 can be written as the sum of squares of two different integers.

For example:

$$8^3 - 7^3 = 13^2 = 12^2 + 5^2$$

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is true of any odd square... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: @BrandonCarter i want to know how can i prove this.

Comment: @BrandonCarter. Maybe I  mis-understand you. None of $9,49, 81,...$ etc., is the sum of two squares.If $(n+1)^3=n^3=m^2>1$ then what we need to show that $m$ has a prime factor congruent to $1 \mod 4.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see that
$$n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2-3n+1.$$
By looking at congruences modulo 4, we see that 
$$n^3-(n-1)^3 \equiv 1\pmod 4.$$
Recalling that you assumed that the difference was a square, you can apply [Fermat's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) cited above to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Im pretty sure youve heard of an identity $$ a^3-b^3=(a-b)*(a^2 +  b^2 + ab) $$ 
If the above is a perfect square then it must be of form $a+b=n$ and $a^2 + b^2 + ab = n x^2$.
Now you can proceed. I think this method is good for an approach. This way you'll realize why mod 4 is so important for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

By expanding, we get $x^2=3n^2+3n+1$
Thus $4x^2-1=12n^2+12n+3=3(2n+1)^2=(2x-1)(2x+1)$
$gcd(2x-1,2x+1)=1$,
We have two cases.
Case 1: $2x-1$ can be written as $3k^2$
Hence 2x+1 is a perfect square and 3|(2x+1)-2. No solution.
Therefore $2x-1$ must be a perfect square. Let it be $(2a+1)^2$.
Then $x=2a^2+2a+1=a^2+(a+1)^2$ QED

Note: I came up with this solution myself, but it also turned out to be the official solution for the IMO Longlist problem.